How to Setup recaptcha on Ionic Capacitor React
Does anyone manage to make recaptcha work on ionic?
I'm planning to use Appflow for our deployment purposes.
I managed to make it work in my local environment, but my problem is when I deployed it on appflow. It has an error "is not in the list of supported domains for this site key."
I'm using the package react-google-recaptcha.
<ReCAPTCHA
    ref={recaptchaRef}
    name="captcha"
    sitekey={siteKey}
    onChange={onChange}
    onExpired={() => {
        recaptchaRef.current.reset();
        onExpired();
    }}
/>

Mobile apps don't have domains right, so how do I make this work?
Or is there an alternative for recaptcha for mobile apps to prevent spam?

Have you tried switching to mobile specific recaptcha packages like safetyNet for Android or recaptcha ios sdk? Your implementation with  react-google-recaptcha component of Appflow works well for web based applications but might be problematic in a mobile app environment, due to domain verification requirements.
However, you can consider this a work around if you want to maintain the use of react-google-recaptcha package

set the domain to localhost in the google recaptcha admin console
you will still implement the serverside validation

capture the recaptcha response on the client side
<ReCAPTCHA
  ref={recaptchaRef}
  name="captcha"
  sitekey={siteKey}
  onChange={onChange}
  onExpired={() => {
    recaptchaRef.current.reset();
    onExpired();
  }}
/>

Also, on your server verify the validation using siteverify
const axios = require('axios');

// Example POST request for server-side validation
const verifyRecaptcha = async (recaptchaToken) => {
  const secretKey = 'your_secret_key';

  const response = await axios.post(
    `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`,
    {},
    {
      params: {
        secret: secretKey,
        response: recaptchaToken,
      },
    }
  );

  const { success, score } = response.data;
  if (success) {
    // reCAPTCHA was successfully validated
    return true;
  } else {
    // reCAPTCHA validation failed
    return false;
  }
};

